# Eclipse default when multiple ways to run exist

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run a Java app for the first time with <kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd>, I'm presented with "Run As" dialog asking me to answer "Select a way to run Xyz.java" with a couple of options (in my case Java Application and Spring Boot App). Is there a way to default this to one of these?

Comment: @Elias Doesn't seem that it's a duplicate. My question is about launching for the first time, not re-launching an already-existing config.

Comment: By default, you can use the shortcut sequence Alt+Shift+X, J to run it directly as Java application (or execute the _Run Java Application_ command via Quick Access (Ctrl+3)).